# Attempt to present UIImagePickerController on ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm in trouble, after that I'm moving from View Controller to a second View Controller and then switching back to the View Controller and clicking on the UI Image Picker it's not appearing and bringing me back to the second View Controller. On the debugger it's appearing:

> Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I'm really becoming crazy. My code that is bringing me back from second View Controller to the first View Controller is inside a button and it's below:

```
 @IBAction func profileButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let webVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        webVC.profileLink = linkProfilo
        self.present(webVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in second view controller add this variable:

```
var firstVC: ViewController?
```

and this setter function to set it

```
setup(firstVC: ViewController) { 
   self.firstVC = firstVC 
}
```

in the first view controller, when presenting second view controller pass in a reference to self (first view controller)by calling the setup function

```
let secondVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! ViewController
secondVC.setup(firstVC: self)
self.present(secondVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

now when button is clicked in secondVC,

```
guard let first = self.firstVC else {return}
first.profileLink = linkProfilo
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: If this is from your second viewController and you want to move back, you shouldn't present it on top.

But that's a different problem...

you must be trying to present something after, somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Yes, the code that you seen is from the Second View Controller that will bring me back to View Controller. So what can I do for come back to the first View Controller?

Comment: You should do self.dismiss() so they don't stack on top of each other, but you want to pass the selected image somehow. 

create a setup() function in second view controller:
`setup(firstVC: UIViewController) {
self.firstVC = firstVC 
}`
also create the variable in second view controller, so you can set it:
`var firstVC: UIViewController?`
this way you store a reference to the first view controller from second, and in your button you do 
`self.firstVC.profileLink = linkProfilo`
then dismiss

Comment: so before presenting your second view controller, call the setup function and pass self: `let secondVC = UIStoryboard......`
`secondVC.setup(firstVC: self)`
then present

Comment: I'm really a bit lost... Can you please do a new post with the function "setup" ? thanks

Comment: updated the answer, but remember: This just makes sure you're not stacking view controllers on one another. 
the error you see is probably because you're trying to present something somewhere else

Comment: I'm facing a out another problem now. "Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'profileLink' "
Can it be possible because I need to declare: var firstVC = ViewController and not firstVC: UIViewController? 

ViewController is the name of my first View Controller.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171577/discussion-between-pietro-messineo-and-shayegh).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the way for fix all of this:

```
@IBAction func profileButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if let webVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController {
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                webVC.profileLink = linkProfilo
                dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                appDelegate.window?.rootViewController!.present(webVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
    }
```

it's enough to add the appDelegate sharing method and dismiss before to present the webVC for share the data in the right way and don't cause problems on the first view when presented.